# Do I need to add a return in one of my bedrooms

Tags: hvac, ducts

My house was built in the 70s and the master bedroom has 2 supplies but no return. The other two bedrooms, which are smaller, each have 1 supply and 1 return.

The bathroom right next to the master bedroom has a return, which I've read is a bad place for a return. It's right off the floor and shares a wall with my bedroom so it would be easy to cut through and turn the return around and have it in the bedroom. Is that a good move? I'm wondering if they just made a mistake when they built the house and turned it around accidentally.

I do find it a little cooler in winter/hotter in summer in that room so guessing/hoping this could help with balancing.

The other thing to note is that if I do turn the return around it will be right next to the bedroom door. So I'm also wondering if just keeping the door open would have the same effect or is there still a net positive to turn it around?

Comment: Leaving the door open is an easy and cheap test to see if it makes a difference.  A couple of weeks should be enough to see if the difference is enough or you need more work.

Comment: What is the problem with the current setup? If you leave the door to the bathroom open (except when it's being used), then air from the bedroom can return through it. Even when the bathroom door is closed air can flow under the bathroom door to the return. Having the return in the bathroom allows fast clearance of moist air from the bathroom. Do not change anything unless there is a problem. At least investigate this more fully before you change the return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping the door open will help if there is a return in the hall but if you are working to solve this a solution that requires keeping the master bedroom door open isn't the best.

Turning the master return around is a good idea. Some bathroom air will return through the bedroom but at least it won't be spread directly through the whole house.  Turning it around and also adding a bathroom exhaust fan will probably be ideal.

Two vents in the master and a return in every room you'll be able to play with balancing quite precisely.